# Can any sort of Plant evolve into an Advanced Animal Race?

Tags: evolution, earth, flora

Can plants evolve into something as advanced animal race like humans or even any sort of animal? This plant is on earth-like conditions and there is no Major race like humans that live on the earth.

Comment: yes ... pretty much anything can become anything given enough environmental stress

Comment: There is a question about plant intelligence that may be an interesting addition to the answers you get here: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/43962/how-would-hormonal-sentience-work-and-affect-the-way-a-brain-works-in-a-plant-or/

Comment: Another similar question about the evolution of sapient plants: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/how-could-a-sentient-plant-evolve-and-what-conditions-would-be-required-for-this/10761#10761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes.

And by yes I mean, it would be hard, and probably the plants that have evolved into that sentient being won't look anything like your plants. But, it's not impossible.

## 1) Awareness

First things first. The in the early evolutionary chain of the plant-being, you need to have sense of awareness of the environment, not just to respond to it. It's going to be that sense that will develop into an complex form of intelligence.

## 2) Mobility

I think a second mandatory pre-requisite is the need for mobility. See, probably **the most important difference in early evolution of multicellular organisms is "I can make food of my own staying put" and "I need to go find my food"**. Staying put and at same time make your own food is really good to a microorganism, it leads to a less consumption of energy (to move from a place to another consumes energy). In this stage, something need to driven the need for mobility.

Awareness will help with this, **the being need to know that the environment it's no longer useful to him, and he needs to move to another place.** This need and being capable of move will make the the proto-plant-being you put them into a lot of more stress, making it better developed to his surroundings.

## 3) Sexual Reproduction

In some point, they have to develop a sexual reproduction, it's a really better way to evolve, in the sense that evolution is the preservation of a useful mutation, if you see the [timeline of evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_evolutionary_history_of_life), are going to see that **sexual reproduction leads to a really fast expansion in evolution.**

Mobility will help with that. Since your being already have the awareness of the environment, and are capable of locomotion through it, would not be difficult to change the way that it reproduces.

## 4) A really hard competition.

Human beings probably would not evolved into intelligent beings if was not very difficult to survive. We had a pretty hard competition, a lot of apex predators to dispute food with, with stronger and better inborn tools. Our better, and most developed tool was our survivability from the times when we aren't the hunter. The prey need to be smarter the hunter to survive, it was the process to change from prey to hunter that get the better us.

## Conclusion.

As I said earlier, probably yes. But I down know if we would recognize this being as a plant. To us, plants are things that do photosynthesis, stay put and do what he needs to do by trowing stuff into the environment in contrast to go an getting that animals do.

To me, the photosynthesis will have to go. It's very useful, but at same time, nullifies the need to **"go and get"**. This is the very basic fuel to evolution, it what drives the survival of the better fitted. Plants do their stuff where they are. And **most count with external help to do essential parts of their life cycle life**, like reproduction.

So yes, its possible, but very unlikely.

Comment: the question was not about planets becoming plants that look like animals but about plants that become actual  animals.

Comment: @άλεξμιζέρια who said anything abou planets?

Comment: my bad spelling , i meant plants

Comment: @άλεξμιζέρια **OP** asked if a plant can evolve to an "advanced animal race like humans". I said yes, but probably to us humans, that would not be anything like a plant.

Comment: yep , just said that op was not interested if this animal would look like a plant

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say yes, with a very strict condition. You must justify a reason for plants to need to be intelligent and communicate.

That's going to be the hard bit. As soon as you can do that they're free to evolve into an advanced race.

This means that in practice the answer is no. You're better off waiting 100million years for some sort of animal life to evolve to intelligence.

Answer (score 1):

There have been studies which show that [plants can communicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hormonal_sentience) to each other (by means other than speech) to warn other plants of potential harm.

Some plants have evolved to move/flex to catch prey, such as the Venus flytrap.

It sounds perfectly reasonable that a plant could evolve to show the signs of consciousness that you're talking about, but it may not be obviously visible to humans.